# How do I sync apps to my iPhone with iTunes 12.7 or later?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios-appstore

I’ve got an iPhone 4S that I still use, but the WiFi chip has died. I want to try the hairdryer and freezer trick (I used it once before) but in the meantime I want to be able to add apps to it through iTunes. However, somehow the Apps tab is gone. Is there a way to get it back?

Help would be appreciated a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the release of iTunes 12.7, Apple removed the ability to browse, download or install iOS apps via iTunes for macOS/Windows.

In case you wish to browse App Store on your Mac/Windows PC, you can still download the last version of iTunes (iTunes 12.6.3) with App Store built-in via the Apple Support article, [Deploy apps in a business environment with iTunes](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208079).